# Compiling a dynamically generated java class

Tags: java, json

We have a requirement where we have to generate a java pojo class dynamically using json schema.
Till now we are able to generate the class on the fly(jsonschema2pojo library), but unable to compile the class for further processing.
For compilation classloader should get the class but as the java class is getting generated dynamically, class loader  does not get it and throws InvocationTargetException.
Is there any way of compiling the java package again like using some maven plugin or some other way?

Thanks,

Vaishali Mangwani

Comment: When do you generate the classes? Is it part of your build or you generate the source inside your application at runtime?

Comment: .java is getting created at runtime in a folder.. now need to compile it and load it.. so that the application can use it at runtime..

Comment: I think you should provide some sample codes to give us some ideas about what's exactly happening. I don't know how are you compiling the generated sources? How  did you setup the classpath for your application? etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven then you can configure plugin. https://joelittlejohn.github.io/jsonschema2pojo/site/1.0.1/generate-mojo.html.

Which will build your POJOs.

For example in "pom.xml" we are using:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-alpha4</version>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/schemas</sourceDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            <targetPackage>com.package</targetPackage>
            <useCommonsLang3>true</useCommonsLang3>
            <includeAdditionalProperties>false</includeAdditionalProperties>
            <includeConstructors>true</includeConstructors>
            <useLongIntegers>true</useLongIntegers>
            <inclusionLevel>ALWAYS</inclusionLevel>
            <generateBuilders>true</generateBuilders>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.json</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        ...
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

In our case we have POJO's as separate package/library, so it can be shared between projects.

If you need runtime compilation, then tools like https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler could help, but this gets more involved and from the looks it does not make sense in your case.

Comment: I am using jsonschema2pojo and keeping the .java class inside a folder outside the source.. now facing an issue of creating .class file of the same and lading it runtime.. so in short in a single flow it is.. .java -> .class -> load .class for runtime use.. but still facing issue in 2nd step..